# how to use cucumber-jvm reports with Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber-jvm

I'm using DSL scripts in Jenkins Pipeline job - how to use cucumber-jvm reports plugin in DSL script and show the cucumber report in Jenkins job.

If someone can help me to achieve this - that would be really appreciated.

I've free style Jenkins job which has cucumber-jvm reports plugin - so I'm getting cucumber report in chart view - but getting stuck with Jenkins Pipeline job and how to bring cucumber jvm report in it using DSL scripts

**Sample DSL code:**

```
node {
    stage "Execute Junit Test"

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do that in our testing:

```
pipelineJob(string jobname){
    publishers {
        cucumberReports {
            jsonReportPath('reports/')
        }
    }
}
```

You can check this [doc](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/) and adjust the code according to your project

Comment: Thanks Chong. I'm not able to view the doc - its asking for credentials. Could you please help me to view that. And I've updated my sample dsl which I'm using in pipeline. Can I use your code under node > stage ?

Comment: Sorry for giving you the doc on my server, https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/ this should work for you

Comment: I am not sure about 'Can I use your code under node > stage' because I haven't used these "node" or "stage" APIs. Could you show me where you view these APIs?